# Why does the BufferedReader create a growing amount of surviving generations?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I read a 70 million line text file line-by-line. In this simple application the amount of surviving generations keeps growing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String file = "myFile.gz";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), "Cp1252"));

        String inputLine;

        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // here's nothing
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the profiler graph:
[image]

Why do they survive the garbage collector? I thought a growing amount of surviving generations is a bad sign and are for instance the result of a memory leak.

Comment: Please mention the JDK version you are using. Does the profile report say anything about the type of objects surviving e.g. `int`,`string` etc. ?

Comment: And tell us what you're doing with each 'inputLine'.

Comment: @Santosh I use JDK 6. [Graph of surviving objects](http://abload.de/img/1_quickq3srh.png)

Comment: @EJP I use the code I posted above

Comment: Your graph shows `7532680` bytes takes by `char[]` which should be 37.7% of all memory. So your memory consumption is something like 20MB. In other words: nothing. So there's probably no GC at all???